# Wordpress: Can I add categories/tags to all sites in my network at once?

Tags: tags, categories, multisite

I've installed Wordpress 3.1.2, and have enabled the multi-site network.  Each employee in my department can now have their own company blog.

I was hoping to provide a bunch of pre-defined categories & tags for all the sites in the network for consistency between the blogs.  It would be great if I could enter these once, and have them add to all the sites in the network.

Is there a way to do this, or something similar?

Many thanks,
Glen